Under physicalism, what is the ontological status of the laws of logic, and what is their relationship to the laws of physics?
SCOPE: I'm seeking answers from the perspective of physicalism.
If physicalism is true, what is the ontological status of the laws of logic, and what is their relationship to the laws of physics? Are the laws of logic ontologically fundamental, just as the laws of physics are? Are the laws of logic a subset of the laws of physics? Are the laws of logic prior to or more fundamental than the laws of physics? Or are the laws of logic merely human concepts (stored physically as ideas in human brains), developed as humans noticed patterns in reality that could be expressed logically? In that case, could one argue that logic is an emergent phenomenon derived from the laws of physics, which are fundamental?
See also: How does physicalism interpret mathematical theorems in physicalist terms?

NOTE: As of now, there is no official tag laws-of-physics, so I used the tag laws-of-nature instead. If someone takes issue with this, please let me know in the comments. Relevant discussion: Is there a distinction between laws of nature and laws of physics?

Which version of logic am I talking about?
Good question. Wikipedia has a disambiguation page that considers 3 cases:

Law of logic may refer to:

Basic laws of Propositional Logic or First Order Predicate Logic
Laws of thought, which present first principles (arguably) before reasoning begins
Rules of inference, which dictate the valid use of inferential reasoning


My greedy self would encourage answers to ideally cover all three cases. However, if I were forced to only pick one, I would likely choose laws of thought which seem pretty fundamental.

Addressing the charge of duplicate: this question is NOT about mathematics
This question is about logic, not mathematics. Assuming an equivalence between logic and mathematics is controversial, see:

Can mathematics be reduced to arbitrary axioms and logic?
What is the difference between logic and mathematics?
What is the philosophical ground for distinguishing logic and mathematics?

See also the meta discussion: How is a question about logic a duplicate of a question about math?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Physicalism and consistency (hence logic) are immiscible.  See. More authoritative version here

Are you looking for any good response? or are you more in search of an explanation of the controversy?

@JD The two are not mutually exclusive, so I'd be happy to receive answers that tick both boxes :D

@user80226 Okay. Just checking, because I'm almost done reading a theory that addresses this question, and I'll just recapitulate that theory as a lead for you.

You ask what the ontological status is of the laws of logic under physicalism.
Physicalism states that there are only fermions and bosons and the four forces of the standard model of physics. Since the laws of logic have meaning we have to ask where does this meaning reside and what does it constitute of? My claim is that it resides in the brains of people.
The brain is physical and consists of nerve cells that are made up of molecules. The molecules are made up of atoms and atoms are made up of neutrons and protons in the nucleus that are held together by the strong nuclear force. Neutrons and protons in turn are made up of three quarks each, which are fermions. Around the nucleus we find electrons (other fermions) that are configured in orbitals around the nucleus of the atom under the influence of the electromagnetic force. There is also the weak nuclear force, but unless you have eaten a lot of bananas with radioactively decaying potassium-40 isotopes, they do not really have any effect on your thinking about the laws of logic. Neither does the gravitational force that holds you sat in your chair. It has been shown that you can perfectly well think about the laws of logic in free fall around the planet.
Electron configurations in atoms are governed according to probability distributions that depend on the wave functions. These electron configurations or orbitals determine the  chemical reactions that lay at the basis of the biochemistry that makes up the neurons in your brain. At the level of living cells, quantum effects have completely decohered and need no longer concern us, unless we want to discuss the microtubules theory of Penrose and Hamerhoff. Biochemistry is responsible for the incredibly rich landscape of interactions between macromolecules within the cells of which your body is made up. Examples are DNA and RNA, which are both polynucleotides, and proteins that consist of amino-acids. Almost everything in your body is done by proteins that are coded for by the DNA in the nuclei of your cells. These proteins keep the cell alive, keep the metabolism going, dispose of the waste, produce proteins when needed, and what not.
Since you are a multicellular organism you consist of a large number of cells that live together in your body. These cells that live in your various organs, have their own drives to survive, that is, to maximise their metabolism, to divide and multiply and to commit to cell repair. They have no knowledge of the rest of your body. They only know about their local environment. Neurons, the cells that make up your brain, are typical cells that have specialised in communicating. They can send and receive signals. All cells, including the precursors of neurons in our evolutionary distant forbears, communicate with other cells via protein channels embedded in the cell membrane that allow specific ions (Calcium 2+) to move across the membrane. This enables single cells to communicate with other cells. Neurons over millions of years of evolution have specialised in this art and have formed axons that transmit signals away from the cell body to other neurons, and dendrites that receive signals from other neurons. No neuron has any idea what it is firing for or what the higher meaning of it all is. It is just following the deterministic laws of nature. It is for this reason that you have no free will.
The neurons have over time formed a gigantic network with around 80 billion neurons or so, and that is you, your memories, your hopes and desires and your laws of logic. This is all in the connectome or the wiring diagram of your brain. This network is comparable with artificial neural networks where the weights of the nodes in the neural network are analogous with the strengths of the dendrites.
Obviously, the brain is far more complex with many more connections, and much more structure in the various lobes, the amygdala, the hippocampus and other anatomical structures in the brain, all with their particular functionality like the visual cortex, the auditory cortex, the prefrontal cortex where a lot of the decision making is done, et cetera. The brain is mainly concerned with maintaining homeostasis in the body. That is, keeping you alive. Not because it wants to, but because natural selection selected for brains that were good at keeping their bodies alive. That is why it is much harder to kill a mosquito than a carrot. It is because they have brains too. The mosquitos, I mean.
After this physical description of the low level structure of the brain we have to concern ourselves with the processes which will have to explain our beliefs in laws of logic and what not. To see what drives thinking, we could think of it as an information processing system that implements thermodynamic principles that naturally arise, following the laws of physics. On the level of neurons or nerve cells as well as on the level of brains there is a principle at work that is known as the free energy principle. According to this principle, thinking can be understood as your brain's continuous process of minimising free energy by actively predicting sensory information from your environment and updating its internal model based on new sensory input. It essentially tries to minimise surprise and maintain a stable state through perception and action. This means that your thoughts are essentially predictions about what you expect to encounter in the world, which are constantly refined through interaction with your surroundings. In other words: your brain is constantly hallucinating with constant updates from your perception to stay as close to reality as possible. If you get very little input, e.g. when you are asleep, this turns into dreaming. The other lever is action. Instead of updating your model you can also undertake action to minimise the surprise, that is, minimise the free energy. This mechanism is also called active inference.
I just mention the free energy principle here because it is in my opinion a good attempt to explain agency. Once we have agency, we have will, the will to live. This agency in its more primitive form is just trying to minimise surprise. Another way of thinking about minimising surprise is thinking of it as minimising the chance of ending up dead. That would be a surprise.
Now, for finding the elusive locus of our laws of logic we will look at the connectome. The connectome is the wiring diagram where the dendrites form the wiring of the interconnected neurons. These dendrites have much more functionality than the linear connections in artificial neural networks such as non-linear integration of post synaptic signals. So instead of the weights centered on the nodes, it uses these dendrites to facilitate signalling or firing to other neurons. These are the neural pathways that in a process of learning become stronger or weaker. Firing neurons along these neural pathways then form patterns that can be thought of as neural correlates of thoughts, feelings and perceptions. Neurons that wire together, fire together, in so called neural ensembles. Now, when we are not thinking about the laws of logic, and for me that is most of the time, these laws of logic will in some way exist as neural pathways that can be conserved (myelinated) or can be changed in a process of neural plasticity. This means that our beliefs can be updated. In other words: we can learn.
In order to understand what is going on, it is good to realise for a moment that your brain, the wetware, is located inside a dark skull and is hermetically isolated from the outside world. The only input is different signals coming in from your senses, through the optical nerve for example. These are just electrochemical signals traveling along nerve cells via the dendrites in your brain. Some electrochemical signals in your visual cortex, in the back of your brain, will create a sensation of green, while other electrochemical signals in your olfactory bulb will conjure up memories of the apple pie you tasted when you were a child.
Everything you know about the world, including your autobiographical history, your beliefs, your hopes, your desires, your colours, your favourite music, your favourite shows on television, your knowledge of the world, your laws of logic et cetera, all this exists only in your brain. There is nothing you know, you feel, you doubt, you are afraid of, that is not in your brain. Your brain has constructed a model of the world with a model of you inside that model of the world. That means when you touch your feet, then inside your brain, there is the model of you feeling the feet of the model of you, within the wider model of the world, which could be at that moment sitting in your room. It is this model that is feeling pain. It is this model that thinks it has consciousness. The model can be seen as a simulation.
Every idea you have can only be an idea as part of the model that you created. This must be true, because neurons, nerve cells, can’t have any ideas. These ideas can only live in the simulated model of you yourself in the model of the world that lives in your brain. This model is why you can’t know reality. The model can only be an approximation of reality. Not only that, but it also has all sorts of features that do not exist in the real world outside your skull. In the outside world there are no colours as you experience them. There are electromagnetic waves that have certain wavelengths, but only inside your model of the world do they map on the qualia that you appreciate as colours. There are of course no sounds in the outside world, just as little as there are any smells. The smell of a rose is just the mapping of certain olfactory receptors in your nose that connect exactly with organic molecules that give rise to that smell. In the real world there are no smells, just particularly shaped molecules.
In the real world there is no pain, no anger, no fear, no cold and no warmth. These are sensations and emotions that help your body stay alive. They only exist in you and you may infer that other versions of these feelings live in other brains if your model of the world is sophisticated enough to allow for empathy. Your model of other brains in other people gives rise to your theory of mind.
It now becomes clear that the only place where the belief in the laws of logic can live is in this model of the world that you’ve been developing since your youth. This model is encoded in the connectome in your brain. The laws of logic lead a dormant existence within that connectome just like a similar entity exists in the vector space of an LLM. The idea of the laws of logic only surfaces when your brain accepts a query or a request to figure out as to what the laws of logic are, where they apply and what you think of them. This is when the pattern gets activated. They come into focus and you become conscious of them. The vast majority of our thinking or mental processing is unconscious. You don’t know how that works because you have no access, no reporting about the neural ensembles doing all the groundwork. There could be multiple drafts of thinking being processed simultaneously in your brain. You could think of them as threads and when one becomes dominant because the neural paths are amplifying each other and you can hence infer that it is important. It then becomes the process that is broadcast to the rest of the brain where you become aware of it. When the question arises in your consciousness do you know about the laws of logic?, your brain may simply apply a heuristic and the answer is yes. You probed the words ‘laws’ and ‘logic’ and they sounded familiar, so even if you do not know that for sure, you are confident enough that you know about them.
Now you are asked about the ontic status of the laws of logic and this becomes puzzling. Since you live with the illusion that your model of the world is the real world, a concept that normally in the everyday world works surprisingly well, you tend to think that ideas in the world must exist somewhere in that world. How else could you even think about them? But as we have seen, there are many qualities (and ideas) that are an integral part of your simulation and yet, don’t exist. People are convinced that smells are  part of the real world but no matter how we turn it, there are only molecules that chemically fit in certain receptors and send certain signals that then are modelled as ‘smell’. Molecules don't have a smell. What could it possibly consist of? It is simply not real.
So, on one level, you think that the laws of logic are part of the real world because you confuse the real world with your model of the world. In your model of the world you also have a model that represents the world of philosophy with philosophers communicating social constructs that relate to the laws of logic that you know must exist. But that is only a model whereas in reality there is only a specific category of brains that belong to people that share these ideas of the laws of logic. This has the additional problem that they may entertain different ontological accounts of these laws. This also sheds a light on the problem of intersubjectivity. This is the fine tuning of models in brains with models in other brains till they are in agreement. This gives rise to the value of money, for example. If all our simulations agree on the value of money, then money has value. A squirrel who doesn’t run this simulation, rightfully ignores money because it is not edible. Squirrels mostly run simulations that have to do with food or other squirrels.
Many of the problems of the ontology of abstract ideas, numbers, differential equations, fictional characters, confabulations, gods, souls, conspiracy theories, histories, and so on and so forth, are due to the fact that they are part and parcel of our model of the world that is encoded in our neural connectome. It also gives a place to folk-psychology where we categorise our explanations of our hopes and desires and our projections of other minds. But these too only live in our simulation of the world, in the matrix that we’ve created. They don’t exist in the real world. What would hopes and desires look like in terms of atoms and molecules?
In a way, comparable to the vector space of artificial neural networks, these ideas are living in multi dimensional spaces that can only be accessed by the right input that will trigger certain neurons firing along certain pathways to other neurons.
The laws of logic are similarly represented by a pattern in our connectome that under the right circumstances gets triggered to instantiate a temporary idea of the laws of logic. When you are questioned, or you read, or you freely associate, those circuits in your brain will trigger other neighbouring circuits that, given enough potential, will come to prominence in your awareness and you connect the laws of logic with other ideas like implication, proposition, the modus tollens, and the peculiar symbols that are used in first order logic and so forth.
It is also possible that in fact you don’t know anything really about the laws of logic but you are aware that there are these laws that according to other people that you have modelled in your simulation of the world, have significance and you must assume that they therefore exist. You are ignorant of where they exist other than presumably in the modelled brains of the modelled philosophers of your model of the world. Their nature is then no more than an empty reference.
Your follow up question was: what is their [the laws of logic] relationship to the laws of physics?
You can now hopefully see that this is an entirely different question… I think of this as a category mistake. You already presuppose an ontology of the laws of logic that can relate to the laws of physics. All these laws are just abstractions that we infer in order to understand the world better. We weave them in our simulations, so to say, but that’s the only place where they exist and while we marvel at them, fermions are just fermions and bosons are just bosons, blissfully unaware of any of that.
This was my attempt to ELI5 the physicalist point of view.

+1 "Als ik even, nogmaals,de samenvatting mag geven/want anders komen we natuurlijk niet verder." (Kopland, Een lege plek om te blijven)

"The brain is wider than the sky, for, hold them, blue to blue, the one the other would absorb, as sponges, buckets do." - Emily Dickinson

This is a personal articulation of eliminative reductive physicalism.  Note that eliminative reductive physicalism has been rejected as a valid POV by the vast majority of the philosophers of science, philosophers of mind, philosophers of chemistry, biology , etc.  See the SEP articles on Scientific reductionism, and the specific philosophies of science.  You have not gone looking for the failed test cases for this programme.  The denial of the existence of so much of our world, in order to hold onto a THEORY, is to invert the core principle of science.  Evidence trumps theory.

Additionally, very few actual physicalists hold by eliminative reductionism.  Asserting it to be the "physicalist" position is contrary to actual physicalism.  It is ONE version.  I tend to agree with you that it is the original view, and the purest version, and the only one that is internally fully self-consistent.  But self-consistency, and purity -- those are THEORETICAL virtues, not empirical ones.  If one is making claims about the nature of our world, then one should start with observations, and build a model based on them.  This leads to pluralism, not eliminative reductionism.

The answer from a physicalist perspective may be that they simply do not exist and hence there is no need to talk about what it means for them to “physically” exist.
If the response to this is that it is self evident that they exist, I ask you to implore what makes you think this. We only ever have conscious experiences that may relate to an an idea, but never the idea itself.
Logic, just like math, are concepts that supervene on the physical. They do not exist except as descriptions of physical reality. In a sense, they are always attached and inherent to physical reality but they don’t, independently, exist.

So, would you say that for a physicalist the laws of physics do exist but the laws of logic do not?

@user80226 it depends on what you mean by “exist”. Do the numbers apart from our conscious experience of those mathematical concepts exist? I don’t think so. The same applies to the equations in the laws of physics.

But then for a physicalist, what ontologically fundamentally exists that makes things behave regularly?

@user80226 the physical substances/powers that can only be attempted to be described by mathematical equations that are the laws of physics

What are your thoughts on this?

@user80226 my thoughts are that chat gpt is not a reliable source and that this is a good example of it. It makes no sense for laws of physics to be more fundamental than logic when one can’t even talk about physical concepts without logic

We can't even talk about laws of physics without language, therefore language is more fundamental?

Btw, ChatGPT rebutted your comment here.

@user80226 the response talks about how logic may not be prior to physical systems, since it may supervene on the physical, which is what my answer is in agreement with and already outlined. Thus, it doesn’t rebut what I said. This is different from saying that the laws of logic rely on the laws of physics. Both are technically abstract entities, unless you are referring to the laws of physics by the physical substances that behave according to those laws

Anyways, this site is not about responding to certain chat gpt prompts

@Lowri What would it take for you to believe that an AI can have those abilities?

@user80226 Example of a chat gpt link that directly asks your question but with different answers, just to show how flexible chat gpt is

@user80226: determining whether an AI understands the output it is producing you say huge question of its own and not able to be addressed in comments. For large language models such as chat GPT, this simple answer is that we understand how they operate, and there really is no opportunity for them to build semantic understanding; they are simply probabilistic text generators writ large.

@keshlam Would you say the same thing about biological neural networks (e.g., human brains)?

@keshlam See this question: Does the success of AI (Large Language Models) support Wittgenstein's position that "meaning is use"?

@user80226: Give me that level of understanding of how brains process data, and I will give you an answer.

"Give me a long enough lever and a place to stand, and I will move the earth."

@ScottRowe Google AI overview: A lever that could move the Earth would need to be about a quadrillion lightyears long. This is one and a half billion times the distance to the Andromeda galaxy. This is a stern warning that these AI tools are turning out rubbish! In reality it is only 10^23 m or 10 million lightyears. I couldn't get it to repeat this answer. Again: don't trust this garbage.

@Philomath if I meet Archimedes in the afterlife, I'll get him up to speed on his assertion :-)

If we understand by this that everything in the world can be traced back to physical processes, then there is no ontological logic in the world. Logic belongs to the subject and has nothing to do with ontological questions; however, it helps us understand the world. Logic is part of our cognitive structure, emerging as a function of pure reason and the understanding.
As Weizsäcker wrote (and this is indeed true, though it cannot be proven here due to its extensive nature), anyone who can analyze the capacity for thought with sufficient intellectual rigor should be able to deductively derive the fundamental principles of physics. This yields a real world that operates according to certain principles. The things-in-themselves are then real, and the deduction of the principles helps us to understand them. Within the framework of the cognitive apparatus, we then grasp what logic truly is, but this has nothing to do with the principles themselves.

Planck’s Law of Black-Body Radiation was basically discovered as a statistical fudge that turned out to be actual quantum phenomena. Almost a fortuitous lack of rigour. Weizsäcker seems to be one who believes a Theory of Everything is within reach.

@Chris Weizsäcker simply outlines a way to arrive at such a theory. The only way that makes sense to me, because it is based on deduction and not on guessing. The latter depends on luck.

Physicalism has many varieties, but for the purpose of the discussion we can start from the "axiom" that everything is physical.
If so, human mind (aka: the brain) is physical, irerspective of the fact that our current scientific understanding of the mechanisms of human mind is quite limited (but the results achieved so far are impressive).
Starting from this assumption, we have to be consistent with it asserting that operations and activities of the mind are fundamentally the products of physical processes.
Thus, also language and number sense are so.
Even though the number of concepts and the number of expressions
of a language is always finite, the syntactical processor of our mind can potentially produce an unlimited number of new concepts and expressions.
This fact grounds mind's capability to manage the unlimited iteration of operations, that is the core of the number sequence.
In addition, the syntactical proecssor provides us with transformation rules, from which we get the rules of inference.
The same for the logical concepts and operations: negation, conjunction, abstraction, from which the laws of thought are derived: contradiction, identity.
In a nutshell: logic is both in the mind and in the world.
Logic (and mathematics) are formal and symbolic expressions of our language, and thus they apply to the world simply because (sic!) our language applies to the world.

Some references:

Heike Wiese, Numbers, Language, and the Human Mind (2003),

Gila Sher, Is Logic in the Mind or in the World? (Synthese, 2011),

Larissa J. Kaltefleiter et alii, Does syntax play a role in Theory of Mind development before the age of 3 years? (Infant Behav.and Devel., 2021).



Where's this syntactical processor in the mind or brain? Is it the Russell-like sense-data theory or a kind of private language aka the mentalese?...

@DoubleKnot - added reference. Neither: I'm not asserting that Physicalism is "true" (in what sense?). I'm asserting that IF we adopt it, it must be grounded in scientifc research: specifically, research about functional specialization of the brain, i.e. the localization of a brain region specialized for processing syntactic aspects of the
linguistic signal.

A scientist uses logic to make mathematico-physical determinations of nature.  This is what Heidegger calls the exis­tential conception of science (SZ 357).  Working the same from the physical perspective: nature is available for the scientist to determine mathematico-physical laws and determinations such as electrons, etc.
Ontologically this isn't very deep because it picks up straight from nature as existing and doesn't analyse what existence means. This seems to be the main shortcut that physicalism takes.
Physicalists also like to omit the role of the scientist in the nature they take for granted, but if there are to be electrons and quarks involved in deriving laws and determinations why not via scientists too. They exist.
Logic is much to the fore in the process involved in the scientist's discovery of laws, including cognitive logic. That the laws existed prior to discovery is evident upon discovery but actually prior to discovery, well no one knew F = m a. It only existed in the set of undiscovered laws of nature.
How actual nature is is a mystery, and the scientists make laws that model it.

+1 "Physicalists also like to omit the role of the scientist in the nature" I'd suggest that a large number of physicalists do not omit the role of the observer, particularly in the social sciences. I think it's positivists who like to efface the observer because of their strong commitment to scientific realism and the mind independence of phenomena.

@JD Indeed. It's ambitious of scientific realism to try.  The B Series of time comes to mind. One can see both ways: the A Series with the existential observer determining the present, and the B Series a method that works without the present, (just before & after). The contrast is interesting. But, by one definition, with laws as technically 'models' it does seem to require a mind.

Agreed. And certainly why analytic philosophy should always come with a footnote. * See Continental philosophy for a version that doesn't forget that the universe flows through someone's mind's eye. ; )

Physicalism - and I'm sure what I'm about to say is going to be seen as self-contradictory to some people - doesn't actually have to be the claim that literally everything is physical. A physicalist could take a layered view of reality.
Maybe the base layer is logic and mathematical facts.
The next layer up is the entire multiverse that can be created from those facts.
Then this universe.
Then everything in this universe.
Physicalism CAN just be the statement that that last category - everything in this universe - is physical, BUT that what it means to "Be Physical" rests on a bedrock of non-physical concepts.

Does this view have a name? It would be great if you could add references to authors espousing this view.

@user80226 I don't belieive it has a separate name - as someone who holds this view, I'm pretty sure most of us just call ourselves 'physicalists', and I kind of want to wager that a sizable fraction of people who call thmselves physicalists believe something like that - sizeable as in, maybe greater than 30%, possibly even greater than 50%.

If I had to name it, I might call it "nuanced physicalism" or "Mathematical Platonism + Physicalism" or "Emergentist Physicalism".

Under this view, how do you solve this problem: If the Platonic world exists how would we know?

See also: If mathematical platonism is true, how do biological brains governed by physical laws access eternal platonic mathematical truths?

"sizeable as in, maybe greater than 30%, possibly even greater than 50%" - Are there any sources backing up these statistics?

@user80226 no that's a wager. As in, I think that's true, and I think it with enough confidence to put a ilttle money on it.

@user80226 as for 'how do hysical brains access those truths' - those truths are made apparent by the patterns in the physical world. If the physical world is built on a bedrock of something like plantonic truths, then it's no surprise that we find reflections of those platonic truths all over the place in the physical world.

@user80226 this probably isn't worth much, but ChatGPT says: "Physicalists Who Accept Mathematical Truths as Independent (Platonist Leaning Physicalists): This view is common among scientifically-minded physicalists who see mathematics as indispensable for understanding the natural world but are less concerned with reconciling its existence with physicalism strictly.... Scientific Physicalists: Many physicalists working in scientific fields lean towards views that treat mathematics as indispensable for describing physical laws but are agnostic about whether it has an independent existence."

But how do the Platonic truths causally interact with the physical? How did the physical universe begin to exist, and why did it instantiate Platonic truths?

Fantastic questions that nobody has the answer to @user80226 . There's not any sure-fire way to confirm any of it, it's all conjecture - which is why there's such a wide variety of ideas even among experts in physics and mathematics. One possibility is that every mathematically and/or computationally possible universe exists somewhere, and this is just one of them.

Related: How do mathematical realists explain the applicability and effectiveness of mathematics in physics? (Note: most answers seem to be frame challenge answers that reject Platonism)

But this would be only a token physicalism as you allow a non-physical foundation for reality. Physicalism is the claim that all reality is physical or reducible to the physical.

@infatuated I don't think it's token at all. It would mean nothing you interact with on a daily basis is non physical - all creatures are physical, all minds are physically implemented, there's no souls or ghosts or supernatural gods. All claims about this world are in line with whatever you normally think of as 'physicalism' - the only questions to which the answers aren't, on some level, physical, are questions underlying physics itself. And quite frankly... isn't that what you'd expect? It's what I'd expect. Everything is made up of things unlike itself, should physics itself be the same?

@TKoL The only, and a big, issue is that these other things from which physical things are allegedly made up of look quite different from the physical things. Concepts and matter seem to have quite exclusive properties. And following up on this distinction may lead us to discovering even more substantial non-physical things, like those begrudged souls and ghosts, the possibility of which has been the concern of parapsychologists for over a century with a good deal of plausible empirical evidence already at hand.

@infatuated yes, emergence makes things that are dissimilar from their components. Chairs don't look like the atoms that make them up. Computers don't look or act like the atoms that make them up. But nobody would suggest chairs and computers are not made of atoms.

@TKol That's not a real comparison because chairs share the properties of their atomic constituent parts like occupying space and divisibility, as well as having certain shape and color, etc. Same can't be said of mental phenomena.

@infatuated I actually don't think that's true at all. I think chairs and atoms are pretty much nothing alike.

@TKol Not alike but sharing common fundamental properties such as occupying space, having mass, divisibility, etc. Anyways, you can take this as food for thought.

Under physicalism, the laws of logic must be somehow reduced to brain processes but this leads to a paradox: we explain everything including brain science and physics in terms of logic, but for physicalism to be true, physics must be more fundamental than logic. This is the basic conundrum of physicalism rooted in a failure to acknowledge that meaning and its properties as captured in logic are more fundamental than anything we know about ourselves or the world.
Let's concentrate on some of the properties of meaning. Meanings can be simple and primary, and can be synthetic and secondary. Compare the concept of object with cake. "Object" subsumes "cake", and "cake" implies a lot of constitutive concepts such as food, fiber, sugar, flour, mixture, heat, cooked, etc.
Now there's no conceivable way how these concepts with their logical relations can be represented by neural states. First, there's nothing special in any neural state to represent any particular meaning/concept. You can think up some theory but you'll fail to identify any inherent property to link a neural state to any concept/thought. Indeed, how can meanings involved be represented by neural states that are not fundamentally associated with any meaning, other than "neural state" even which is a conceptual construct imposed Kantian-style by the subjective side of our cognition, i.e. mind, on phenomena.
There is a more serious problem with more universal concepts. What property in a brain state or neutral setting can be said to distinguish a particular concept such as "this stackexchange thread" from a broad concept like "humanity"?! Would the proposed neural states be more higher level or lower level for more universal concepts?  Universal concepts are simpler but broader in significance, whereas particular concepts are more narrow but richer in complexity. How can any proposed neurscientific theory account for these dual problems in addition to more fundamental ones pointed out in the previous paragraph?
It appears that one can't even begin to hypothesize about any of these questions under physicalism, yet the ideological dogma keeps struggling for survival! But there are far better alternatives, among them ones informed by richer phenomena of human existence.
Read my other related answers to these questions:
Is this a good argument against mental causation?
Materialism can cover idealism but idealism cannot cover materialism?
Are we at the end of scientific paradigm shifts?

I think you're referring to the problem of intentionality, or aboutness. There's a whole SEP article about it. I think there are hints in LLMs as to where the solution may be found. LLMs are able to distinguish between concepts like 'this SE thread' and  'humanity '...

@Philomath Intentionality is just another challenge for physicalism. Whether in the context of neural activities or CTM implementations, the correlates are only functional and capture the functional effects of mental phenomena which themselves remain unexplained. As for "aboutness" it's one thing to have a computer code generate functions associated with human intentionality, but quite another to think that the program has any subjective sense of aboutness. CTM fans and physicalists usually fail to notice this distinction.
